# How to backup Linux VPS from Windows via ssh/rsync?

Tags: linux, windows, backup

There are a Linux VPS with my hobby projects and my home computer with Windows 7. Windows client is located behind provider's NAT with dynamic IP.
VPS server is only accessible with ssh.

Is there any backup software for Windows which should connect to Linux VPS via ssh/rsync? What i expect:

- It should make incremental and full backups.
- It should persist unix access mode and user|group owner for files
- It should support logarithmic backup retention.

I have googled for a couple hours and didnt find good solution.